# Help understanding ARM Assembly example code - loops, set flags and code mnemonics

Tags: assembly, arm

This is the example code:

```
_start:
LDR r0, =n
LDR r0, [r0]
LDR r1, =array1
MOV r2, #0
LDR r4, =array2
loop:
LDR r3, [r1], #4
CMP r3, #58
BGT a_point
CMP r3, #47
BLT a_point
SUB r3, r3, #0x30
STR r3, [r4], #4

a_point:
    subs r0, r0, #1
    BGT loop

stop:
    b stop

.Data
n: .word 6
array1: .word 0x30, 0xFFFFFFF5, 0x37, 0x4b, 0x18, 0x40
array2: .word 0x01, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
```

I'm having trouble understanding how the loop works, what it does and specifically how the branch instruction work on pair with the -lt and -gt suffixes. What is the purpose of this simple program? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: could you re-check this code? It's kind of strange that r0 is decremented as a counter and not used within the loop.

Comment: r0 = counter used to check  n  members unconditionally of array   a = array1[1]  if (a >58 || a < 47)  goto dec  n else a = a-30  array1[1] = a & dec n;

Comment: @PawełŁukasik LDR increments the array pointer so there is no need to use the counter for indexing

Comment: I got the code from my course. I double checked and it's correct, even if it's quite weird. I was hoping that someone that knows a bit more than me on assembly for arm could describe to me what's the purpose of the program.